# NieR:Automata settings reset to default on launch

Tags: technical-issues, pc, nier-automata

NieR: Automata keeps resetting my screen and controls settings. I use the custom controller profile, and set the game to run on a particular monitor in fullscreen. The past two times I have loaded the game after boot, the game reverts to the default resolution, forgets which monitor it is supposed to be on, selects Layout A for my controller, and deletes my customized controller layout.

Typically after getting everything back the way I want it, the game seems to hold on to those settings between launches. After shutting down, and then booting my PC the next evening, the settings go back to the default again.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Is there some sort of internal config file that I have messed up somewhere? Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Just to add some closure to this question, I did not do anything, but the game stopped resetting my settings. If you are having problems, do try the steps mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be one of the bugs plaguing the PC release. Fortunately, I've found a handful of potential solutions!

From [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/nier/comments/605bjd/settings_getting_reset_every_time_i_launch_game/):

> [E]very time i launch the game, my sound, camera, and custom control settings get reset. Anyone else seen this happen?
>
> Edit: As far as I can tell, reinstalling fixed it.

A second user in that thread said this worked for them, as well.

If that doesn't fix your issue, two other users found their own fixes for this:

> solved my problem by creating new windows user

And

> I have fixed it as well but in my own way:
>
> - Start Nier (I ran it as Admin, not sure if you need to) and tab to Windows
> - Go to Documents/My Games/
> - Rename the Nier folder (to save it in case it goes wrong)
> - Tab back into the game and put all the settings the way you want them and now they should save properly

Hopefully one of these solutions solves your problem as well!